# vue.js how to get the value of the custom element attribute parameters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the use of vue.js, on the definition of attribute id number how to get it?
I want to $refs read `id="20"` value. I hope console.log is `21,10,15`. go to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/armcfuc1/)

Look at:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fruit: [{
      id: 21,
      name: 'Peach'
    }, {
      id: 10,
      name: 'Apple'
    }, {
      id: 15,
      name: 'Lemon'
    }],
    branid: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in fruit" :id="item.id" ref="branid">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain more ***I want to Refs read branid value inside of number***?

Comment: I want to get it `21,10,15` of vue $refs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply refer to the `branid` key and extract the `id` from each `li` item, see the updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/armcfuc1/2/):

```
console.log(this.$refs.branid.map(li => li.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to get it through this.$refs, it is in your fruit array so you can easily get it by using map or filter function:

Example:

```
mounted() {
    var ids = this.fruit.map(function(obj) {
     return obj.id;
    });
    console.log(ids)
}
```